# Removing doubles from a string

Tags: python, beginner, strings

I've wrote a function where the doubles from a string are removed:

```
def removeDoubles(string):
    output = ' '
    for char in string:
        if output[-1].lower() != char.lower():
            output += char
    return output[1:]
```

For example:

- `removeDoubles('bookkeeper')` = 'bokeper'
- `removeDoubles('Aardvark')` = 'Ardvark'
- `removeDoubles('eELGRASS')` = 'eLGRAS'
- `removeDoubles('eeEEEeeel')` = 'el'

As you see, it will remove every double letter from a string no matter if it's uppercase or lowercase.

I was wondering if this could be more pythonic. As I have to start with a string containing a space, `output[-1]` does exist. I was also wondering if it's possible to use list comprehensions for this.

Comment: How should the word 'godessship' work with your function? From the title it sounds like you want 'godesship', but your code returns 'godeship'?

Comment: Indeed, just 'godeship'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your examples are pretty useful (especially `'Aardvark'`), and should be included in the documentation of the function, ideally as a [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).  However, the problem is still underspecified: what should happen when a streak of three identical characters is encountered?  Should `removeDoubles('eeek')` return `'eek'` (which is how I would interpret "doubles"), or `'ek'` (which is what your code actually does)?

As per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), the official Python style guide, function names should be `lower_case_with_underscores` unless you have a good reason to deviate.  Therefore, I recommend renaming the function to `remove_doubles`.

Obviously, initializing `output` to `' '` and then dropping it with `output[1:]` is cumbersome and inefficient.

Fundamentally, this operation is a fancy string substitution.  Typically, such substitutions are best done using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping).  In particular, you need the *backreferences* feature:

> Backreferences in a pattern allow you to specify that the contents of an earlier capturing group must also be found at the current location in the string. For example, `\1` will succeed if the exact contents of group 1 can be found at the current position, and fails otherwise. Remember that Python’s string literals also use a backslash followed by numbers to allow including arbitrary characters in a string, so be sure to use a raw string when incorporating backreferences in a RE.
>
> For example, the following RE detects doubled words in a string.
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> p = re.compile(r'(\b\w+)\s+\1')
> >>> p.search('Paris in the the spring').group()
> 'the the'
> ```

For my interpretation of "doubles":

```
import re

def remove_doubles(string):
    """
    For each consecutive pair of the same character (case-insensitive),
    drop the second character.

    >>> remove_doubles('Aardvark')
    'Ardvark'
    >>> remove_doubles('bookkeeper')
    'bokeper'
    >>> remove_doubles('eELGRASS')
    'eLGRAS'
    >>> remove_doubles('eeek')
    'eek'
    """
    return re.sub(r'(.)\1', r'\1', string, flags=re.I)
```

To preserve your implementation's behaviour:

```
import re

def deduplicate_consecutive_chars(string):
    """
    For each consecutive streak of the same character (case-insensitive),
    drop all but the first character.

    >>> deduplicate_consecutive_chars('Aardvark')
    'Ardvark'
    >>> deduplicate_consecutive_chars('bookkeeper')
    'bokeper'
    >>> deduplicate_consecutive_chars('eELGRASS')
    'eLGRAS'
    >>> deduplicate_consecutive_chars('eeek')
    'ek'
    """
    return re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', string, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: A [similar question with a similar answer](/q/134556/9357).

Answer (score 3):

This is very good use-case of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). It helps you group similar items if no key function is specified otherwise grouping is done based on the grouping function. In this case we will use `str.lower` as grouping function.

```
from itertools import groupby

def remove_repetitions(seq):
    return ''.join(next(g) for _, g in groupby(seq, str.lower))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> remove_repetitions('bookkeeper')
'bokeper'
>>> remove_repetitions('Aardvark')
'Ardvark'
>>> remove_repetitions('eELGRASS')
'eLGRAS'
```

---

- Also I have renamed it to `remove_repetitions` because we are removing more than doubles here if present.
- New name is using snake-case instead of camel-case. Check [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) for naming-style conventions.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, string addition is a code smell. Whenever you do repeated addition of strings, Python has to create a new string, and copy the two strings being added into that new memory. This is quite slow.

Regardless of anything else, you should at least accumulate your values in a list, for which this is better handled, and `str.join` them at the end:

```
def removeDoubles(string):
    output = ['']
    for char in string:
        if output[-1].lower() != char.lower():
            output.append(char)
    return "".join(output)
```

Note that because the first element is now the empty string, we can join the whole thing, avoiding creating a copy of the whole list at the end.

The reason why strings behave differently from lists is because strings are immutable, while lists are mutable. This means a list can be modified in-place, while a string will always generate a new string.